# CSS drop down menu styling

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have created a CSS drop down menu [HERE ON THIS PAGE](http://hauppauge.com/gaming/index2.htm) in the top main nav.

There is a drop down menu under Products, Support and Community top links.

On this particular page I gave activated a class on the products link so the list item is darker telling the viewer they are on the Products page.

```
<li class="products"><a href="#">products>
```

But when I do this I lose all the styling for the Products drop down menu, it picks up the css styles from its parent Products. I want it to remain looking like the drop down menu for Support and Community.

Any idea how I can do this?

[CSS is HERE](http://hauppauge.com/css/gaming/nav-menu-gaming.css)

Thanks!

Comment: Use `&gt;` rather than `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (nav-menu-gaming.css:113)

```
.menu > li:hover
```

in place of

```
.menu li:hover
```

From nav-menu-gaming.css:126, change

`.products a` to `.products > a`

Comment: Hi, When I do this (change it to .menu > li:hover) it gets rid of the hover effects for the sub menus that are working OK (Support and Community), it does nothing for the Products sub menu.

Comment: @Kim Updated my answer please check

Comment: Hi - for line 126, I should remove the entire linear gradient effect? Yes this does fix the issue with the Products sub menu but it also gets rid of the effect for the main Products link which I do not want.

Comment: I just saw your comment to change it to .products > a and this fixed it - thank you so much!